# WCF Unique ID for each service method call

Tags: wcf

I'm logging using log4net, and I want to log a id that is unique for each serice method call. I dont need it unique across service calls, just within a method call. Is there any built in id i can use in wcf? I don't want to manually create a guid or something at the start of the method call.

e.g.

```
wcfMethod(int x)
{
 log("xxx");
 somework
 log("yyy");
}

private log(string message)
{
   var frame = new StackFrame(1);
   var method = frame.GetMethod();
   var type = method.DeclaringType;
   var name = method.Name;

   var log = LogManager.GetLogger(type);

   // LOG ID HERE
   ThreadContext.Properties["MessageId"] =    OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageHeaders.MessageId; // SOMETHING HERE
}
```

I've tried OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageHeaders.MessageId but thats always null.

I've read about wcf instance correlation but i don't need something that complicated (e.g. unique across different method calls).

Please if anyone can help that would be much apprieciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it important that you find/generate this identifier outside the actual method? Otherwise I'd just send such an identifier from the method in the `log` method call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plain SOAP or REST has no such identification included in messages. You must use some additional feature or transport protocol (for example MSMQ) supporting identifications of messages. In case of `MessageId` you have to use SOAP service with WS-Addressing and this information must be passed from client.