# Fetching MessageId from IParameterInspector

Tags: c#, wcf, logging, serialization

As part of my WCF service, I'd like to log incoming/outgoing calls with the action requested and the input parameters provided.

I'd also like to log the request's `MessageId` in the *same* log line. The `IParameterInspector` looks perfect for this, however the `MessageId` (part of the Message request object) is not available here.

If I implement `IDispatchMessageInspector`, I have access to the Message object, but not the input parameters / action (well technically I do, but it's not trivial getting to them). I'd really like to use the `BeforeCall` functionality of `IParameterInspector`, as it doesn't require any assumption on the message's schema.

I might be missing something very simple, however it seems getting *both* the `MessageId` and input parameters within the same scope is not easy.

Combining `BeforeCall` and `BeforeSendRequest`, or at least passing data between these two methods, would be perfect.

Answer (score 0):

You can use inside your IParameterInspector something like that :

```
OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageHeaders.MessageId
```

Comment: I have tried this, but unfortunately OperationContext.Current is null in the scope of BeforeCall.

Comment: It's weird. It should have been set. What's your configuration ?

Comment: It might be because I'm running the client locally? I am debugging client --> WCF at the moment. BeforeCall is being called on the client-side with a null OperationContext.Current property. No special configuration - in fact it's also null in AfterCall....

Comment: Ooph. After a bit of debugging, it seems OperationContext.Current isn't available if used in a multi-threaded environment. My client spawns multiple threads which access the server, hence why I'm seeing null. I want to avoid adding code to the service implementation itself (e.g. setting threadstatics) and ideally handle everything in the endpoint behaviors, but this doesn't seem trivial :(.

Comment: If you directly create an instance of the service type - as opposed to a WCF proxy/clientchannel - and then you call a method on it, there is no OperationContext. WCF provides an OperationContext instance when your operation is running within a service.

Comment: This'll be what's happening then, as I removed the multi-threaded code and still had a null OperationContext. For reasons I won't go into here, I need to create an instance of the service type directly rather than going through a WCF proxy/channel. Are you aware of any workarounds?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the link [WCF Unique ID for each service method call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7121436/wcf-unique-id-for-each-service-method-call)

Another option is to add a messageproperty in the afterRecieveRequest

```
public object AfterReceiveRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel, InstanceContext instanceContext)
       {

Guid activityId = Guid.NewGuid();
            System.ServiceModel.OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageProperties.Add("LOGID", activityId);
//log your messages here

return activityId 

}

public void BeforeSendReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
       {
            Guid activityId = (Guid)correlationState;
//Log your Message here..
}
```

And in the actual function serving the request you can access this property

```
 public String SayHello(String request)
            {
                object activityId;
                System.ServiceModel.OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageProperties.TryGetValue("LOGID", out activityId);

    //log your messages here with this ID....

Return "Hello, World";
    }
```